# Unable to have aws userdata echo onto /etc/crontab

Tags: cron

Long story short I am trying to have my aws userdata create a cronjob on launch. I am unable to echo into the /etc/crontab location. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
echo '# description of cronjob being addeded' 
echo '0 16 * * 2,4,6 root some commands' | sudo tee -a /etc/crontab > /dev/null
echo ' ' | sudo tee -a /etc/crontab > /dev/null
```

Comment: I figured out how to do it. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer incase someone else needs to know.

```
"sudo sh -c 'echo \"# description of cronjob being addeded\" >> /etc/crontab' \n",
"sudo sh -c 'echo \"0 16 * * 2,4,6 root some commands\" >> /etc/crontab' \n",
"sudo sh -c 'echo  \" \"  >> /etc/crontab' \n",
```